# How to arrange nested divs next to each other using inline block or flex

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

How to arrange nested divs next to each other using inline block or flex

I have 3 elements in my html.

One icon, and two text elements.

I want the icon to be on left and then the text on top of each other.

I am trying to do this using following html and css, which works partially. The icon is way down and I tried moving it up. More over , I think there is a better and right way of doing this.

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2D5DD;
}

.auto-complete-box {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.auto-complete-tag {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tag-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #0083cb;
}

.tag-description {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #798071;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div class="auto-complete-box">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="auto-complete-tag">
    <div class="tag-header">HeaderValue</div>
    <div class="tag-description">Item description</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="auto-complete-box">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="auto-complete-tag">
    <div class="tag-header">Header 2 </div>
    <div class="tag-description">Item description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
The divs are aligned and the icon also aligned to the div(s) on right side , probably by using stretch.

[image]

Comment: you want the `auto-complete-box` and `auto-complete-tag` vertically aligned?

Comment: @kukkuz, Yes, I want them to be vertically alligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` to `wrap` div and remove unnecessary code(`inline/inline-block`)

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2D5DD;
}
.wrap{
display:flex;
}

.tag-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #0083cb;
}

.tag-description {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #798071;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="auto-complete-box">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="auto-complete-tag">
    <div class="tag-header">HeaderValue</div>
    <div class="tag-description">Item description</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="auto-complete-box">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="auto-complete-tag">
    <div class="tag-header">Header 2 </div>
    <div class="tag-description">Item description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, The only issue now is , the Icon is way shorter that elements stacked on right side. Is there a way we can align them properly.

Comment: Updated the question with picture. Thanks!

Comment: when i run code i can not see it... put code in fiddle and let me know the link:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: No worries, I got that. I just applied transform to fa , for stretching up.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler method to use when trying to align components in HTML is to make use of the table structure. Sometimes aligning of certain components don't work when using CSS because there might be a conflicting style element.

So a method I prefer using to ensure that my components are perfectly in line, is to encapsulate them in a table. In your case, put the icon and text element into 2 separate columns within a single row as shown in the code snippet below:

I hope this helps! :)

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2D5DD;
}

.auto-complete-box {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.auto-complete-tag {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tag-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #0083cb;
}

.tag-description {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #798071;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <div class="auto-complete-box">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="auto-complete-tag">
            <div class="tag-header">HeaderValue</div>
            <div class="tag-description">Item description</div>
        </div>
   </td>
   <tr>
   <td>
       <div>
           <div class="auto-complete-box">
           <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </div></div>
       </td>
       <td>
       <div class="auto-complete-tag">
           <div class="tag-header">Header 2 </div>
           <div class="tag-description">Item description</div>
       </div>
       
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this way:

```
.wrap{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it has been downvoted, it meets exactly the requirement. Doing that kind of things will discourage people to contribute...

Comment: Have you tested your solution in the questioner's code? It does nothing. Plus, you don't explain how your solution works. There isn't even a `.wrap` element in the questioner's code. We're not trying to discourage people from contributing. But your answer doesn't contribute anything. It's incomplete and incorrect.

Comment: Absolutely wrong what you are saying. In the first abswer, if you replace the `.wrap` by the one provided, trick is done...

Comment: What do you mean by 1st answer?  The 1st answer is working perfectly fine and that's why it is up voted and marked as an answer.Where as your answer , if copied as it is to the question , will not only 'not answer' , even break existing formatting. I agree that, it could be discouraging , as have happened to numerous of us, but the aim of stack overflow is to provide quality solutions who ever searching for an existing problem

Comment: Are you here answering answers or answering questions? So you're saying that people have to read the question, then read all other answers, then we  can understand your answer? That makes sense to you? What if 2 years from now this question has 46 answers? What if the answer upon which your answer is based is changed or deleted? No my friend, I am not wrong. Your answer is no good.

Comment: If you think your solution is a helpful modification to another answer you should post it as a comment to that answer, not as an entirely separate answer.

Comment: I cannot comment an existing answer, min 50 reputation required